# firebase authentication library conflict

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement Firebase authentication library to do a sign-in process, but the problem is that the app doesn't even compile because of an incompatible version of Firebase authentication and kotlin.

Here's the error message:

```
Class 'com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.AuthKt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin.

Failed to transform firebase-auth-ktx-22.1.1.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:22.1.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=27, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
```

so in short words, the problem is an incompatibility of versions between kotlin and firebase authentication dependency but I don't know how to resolve the compatibility of versions between those libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have these lines in my code

```
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
    auth = Firebase.auth //here comes the problem of (as mentioned in the official documentation) incompatibility of versions
}
```

the purpose of the commented line is to initialize the `auth` with `FirebaseAuth` instance, so simply replace `auth = Firebase.auth` with `auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()`.